# jQuery, how to replace a div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the div content of class="replaceDiv" with a button, "Delete"

```html
Button:   <input type="button" value="Delete" />
====================================================================

<div>
  <div class="col-sm-9" align="center">
    <div class="replaceDiv">
      <a href="/xyz/delta/12">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" name="FISCAL_YEAR_ID">
       <option value="15">FY15</option>
       <option value="16">FY16</option>
       <option value="17">FY17</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this: $('.replaceDiv').html('')

Comment: Replace for what? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to swap out the `<a>` element with the `<div class="form-group">` element? You can remove, copy-paste, or just show hide. There are a number of jQuery examples out there, please post the code that your working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try both 
`$('replaceDiv').replaceWith('<p> new content</p>')
$('replaceDiv').html('<p> new content</p>')`.

It's not clear what you want to do but those should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you want to replace it with, but here's an example how it works in general:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $(".replaceDiv").html("blabla");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="x" value="Delete" />

<div>
  <div class="col-sm-9" align="center">
    <div class="replaceDiv">
      <a href="/xyz/delta/12">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" id="FISCAL_YEAR_ID" name="FISCAL_YEAR_ID">
       <option value="15">FY15</option>
       <option value="16">FY16</option>
       <option value="17">FY17</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank everyone $(".replaceDiv").html("blabla"); worked. But I have a follow up question, the button I replaced with does not work as expected. I mean it is supposed to execute a javascript funtion its not doing once I replace the html. If I try without replacing the script but having it in the html it works fine. Should I do something else after replacing the html.

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to insert into that DIV, or what you mean by "the button I replaced with does not work as expected". Sorry, but if I don't understand you, I can't help you beyond what I already wrote.

Comment: @asreeram try to find out its parent element then apply any event its a dynamic html you are creating you can't assign direclty any event on it.